# Trying to do total word count on all files recursively but the sum is not right

Tags: bash, sum, find

So I do this:

```
find . -name '*.md' -type f -exec wc -w {} \; | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

And get a column of numbers (truncated):

```
...
2829
3619
828
1195
2406
2857
1480
1846
23
```

But then when I pipe all of that into a sum, I get an incorrect amount:

```
find . -name '*.md' -type f -exec wc -w {} \; | awk '{ print $1 }' | sum
9658 2
```

I thought awk would strip the white space out of wc -w output. But am I missing something?

(End result: I want to take a weekly word count and compare it previous weeks.)

Comment: What's this `sum` at the end?

Comment: `sum` is not what you expect I think. `sum` is part of `coreutils`: `sum - checksum and count the blocks in a file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate all the files and pipe the result to `wc -w`, this way you don't need to sum word counts of individual files.

```
find . -name '*.md' -type f -exec awk 1 {} + | wc -w
```

`awk 1` is for making sure each file's content is separated from that of the other with a newline, if that's not necessary, you can use `cat` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your code is that `sum` does not count the sup of the output of the previous command.

Here is the sum help manual

> Usage: sum [OPTION]... [FILE]...
> Print checksum and block counts for each FILE.

Here is what you can do

```sh
find . -name '*.md' -type f -exec wc -w {} \; | awk '{s+=$1} END {printf "%.0f", s}'
```

Where the awk increments the `s` on each step with the value and prints it as an integer (to 0 decimal places) when done.